# Uploading photos to Google photos

Tags: google, upload

I am not able to upload photos from my PC to Google photos. Their web address is 'photos. google. com'. I tried both Chromium and Firefox. Chromium closes down. In Fire fox, it takes a long time, even after which the upload does not happen. Could you please give a solution? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS 64 bit.
Thanks.

Comment: Your files are probably corrupt. I just tested and it works fine in any browser.

Comment: I use those photos for my blogs at blogspot.com. I first upload them to photos.google .com, so that I can arrange them in separate folders (albums). From there, I import them to my blogs. But when the upload fails, I upload the same photos directly to the blog. Then the upload works. But in this method, arrangement into folders is not possible. So I guess, it is not the files being corrupt. It is the problem between the operating system and photos .google.com. Thanks

Comment: There's no problem between the OS and Google, as I already told it works. If not corrupted files then the problem can be related with the browsers profiles but it's hard to believe both failing at the same time.